# Getting 404 error in Jersey with no web.xml

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, jersey

I am following [Jersey tutorial](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/user-guide.html#d4e99) to develop simple Jersey web application.

By following Section - **Example 2.9. Deployment of a JAX-RS application using @ApplicationPath with Servlet 3.0**

I have created created below program:

```
@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class MyApplication extends PackagesResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        super("com.examples");
    }
}
```

and I have below basic Resource class:

```
@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getClichedMessage() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
 }
```

I am using `Jersey-1.19` version, I am not having any web.xml file in my web application. Now I am deploying my application on Tomcat 7 server.

When I try to access the URL as : `http://localhost:8080/myapp/resources/helloworld` I am getting error as

> HTTP Status 404 - /myapp/resources/helloworld
>   type Status report
>
> message: /myapp/resources/helloworld
>
> description: The requested resource is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `jersey-servlet` dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

if you want to go with no web.xml. It has the `JerseyServletContainerInitializer` required to load the application.

---

And just for any future readers that come across this looking for a Jersey 2.x solution, you need the following dependency to work with no web.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

for the same reason - it has the `JerseyServletContainerInitializer`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Please check my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31522824/using-produces-for-different-methods

Comment: I need one more help, the official documentation has not mentioned adding this dependency in pom.xml file, so I feel the document is somewhat incomplete. Should I still continue learning using the same user guide or is there any other better document or book which I can follow to learn Jersey. Please suggest.

Comment: Well it's possible that part of the documentation wasn't updated after version 1.10. That's when the servlet artifact was split. I think even in the new Jersey 2.x, it doesn't mention anything about the artfiact I posted above. Even all the official examples still use xml, where only `jersey-container-servlet-core` is used. This is not sufficient for no web.xml. You need the one above. For learning purposes, it depends on which version you want to learn. If you want to start with 2.x, you can see [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html).